# The implicit unwrapping of an optional boolean

Tags: swift

The implicit unwrapping of a Bool type does not seem to work:

```
var aBoolean: Bool!    // nil
aBoolean = false       // false
aBoolean               // false

aBoolean == true       // false
aBoolean == false      // true

if aBoolean {
    "Hum..."            // "Hum..."
} else {
    "Normal"
}

if aBoolean! {
    "Hum..."
} else {
    "Normal"          // "Normal"
}
```

If I had declared `aBoolean` like `var aBoolean: Bool?`, this would have been the expected behavior but here, I don't get it.

Is this the correct behavior? I didn't find any doc about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm excited to type `if !bool! ...` someday!

Comment: ^ That's what I thought of too! Hah

Comment: That code won't compile. You're missing a curly brace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first test is checking whether aBoolean stores a value rather than nil, which it does:

```
if aBoolean {
    "Hum..."            // "Hum..."
else {
    "Normal"
}
```

The second test is checking against the actual boolean value stored in aBoolean, which is false:

```
if aBoolean! {
    "Hum..."
} else {
    "Normal"          // "Normal"
}
```

This is Illustrated in the Swift book in the "Implicitly Wrapped Optionals" section. I think the implicit unwrapping just doesn't apply with if-statements. I agree it is strange but here is the Apple example:

You can still treat an implicitly unwrapped optional like a normal optional, to check if it contains a value:

```
let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."

if assumedString {
    println(assumedString)
}
// prints "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Yes, but the question is why he needs to unwrap the boolean if the boolean is declared as "implicitly unwrapped" by using the exclamation mark

Comment: @Dash Please see the comment above

Comment: The book says: “You can still treat an implicitly unwrapped optional like a normal optional, to check if it contains a value”, which I think is a hint that this kind of `if` will check for the existence of a value, rather than checking the value itself.

Comment: @MattGibson thanks! Can you add the source in a response and I'll accept it right away? :)

Comment: Thanks @MattGibson! I think we found the quote at the exact same time :)

Comment: BTW as of beta 5, optionals no longer conform to the "BooleanType" protocol, so this ambiguity is no longer possible (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html, check out "If statements and forced unwrapping")

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but if this is indeed the intended behavior with implicitly unwrapped booleans it's rather disturbing. As soon as you use the expression in any logic proposition it will get unwrapped:

```
var aBoolean: Bool! = false

if !aBoolean {
    "I'm unwrapping"            // "I'm unwrapping"
}

if aBoolean == false {
    "I'm unwrapping"            // "I'm unwrapping"
}
```

Say you have this in your code an at some point your model changes and the condition is reversed, you delete the NOT.

```
if aBoolean {
    "I'm unwrapping"            // <- ouch
}
```

You just got screwed. Makes me want to avoid the implicit unwrapping.

Comment: Usually you should avoid implicit unwrapping. It's motivation is cases like `IBOutlets`. Here you have a class with member variables that are still nil after init() finishes, but are assigned a value when the nib is loaded. So from before `awakeFromNib()` onwards, they will never have a nil value, and all the unwrapping would be pointless. These things are Cocoa objects not bools, so the issue you raise doesn't apply.

There may be other similar cases for using implicit unwrapping. But for general use you should be using ordinary conditionals.

Comment: I don't argue that the proper applications of implicit unwrapping are scarce. All I say is I think a better implementation would be for this to behave as a boolean unless you explicitly try to unwrap it with "if let" ...

Comment: The proper applications of implicit unwrapping for a Bool are none existent. Your suggestion would break the use of if with any other implicitly unwrapped type, for no advantage.

Comment: See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842834/swift-good-coding-practice-if-statement-with-optional-type-bool Apple recognizes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are making two different truth-checks.

Given:

```
var aBoolean: Bool!    // nil
aBoolean = false       // false

if aBoolean {
    "Hum..."            // "Hum..."
else {
    "Normal"
}

if aBoolean! {
    "Hum..."
} else {
    "Normal"          // "Normal"
}
```

...in the first `if aBoolean`, the value is not being unwrapped, it is simply testing the optional type to determine if it *stores* a value.

In the second `if aBoolean!`, you are testing the truth-value of the unwrapped Bool.

To see that it *is* indeed being implicitly-unwrapped (when not used in a conditional), try:

`println("value of implicitly-unwrapped aBoolean: \(aBoolean)")`

...this will print 'true' when aBoolean is set to true, 'false' when it is set to false, and 'nil' when it has not yet been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the behavior clearly shown:

```
> var bool1 : Bool!
bool1: Bool! = nil
> bool1 = false
> (bool1 ? "yes" : "no")
$R19: (String) = "yes"
```

In the above, since `bool1` is an *optional* (which becomes a `Some` instance), the conditional of simply `bool1` evaluates to `true` (it is not `nil`).

```
> var bool2 : Bool = false
bool2: Bool = false
> (bool2 ? "yes" : "no")
$R25: (String) = "no"
```

When `bool2` is not an *optional*, the conditional of simply `bool2` evaluates to `false` (the value of `bool2`)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a variable as "implicitly unwrapped", using the `!`, it is still an `Optional`

This type of variable behaves very much like the standard variable type in Objective-C. It can be assigned to `nil`, but when you access members you do not need to explicitly unwrap it. In this way it is "unsafe" just like in ObjC because you can be accessing properties from nil

Thus, it is used most commonly when bridging from Objective-C. However, it is still an optional, with the only difference being you don't need to unwrap it to access the contents.

I believe this was added mostly to support interop between Swift and Obj-C and might be good practice to sparingly use it in pure Swift code. (Swift guidelines are a fuzzy thing right now and someone might prove me wrong soon!)

Comment: In pure swift they are useful for IBOutlets. These are nil until the nib has been loaded, but from then on they have a value. Checking the value each time would be tedious. But here they are used for Cocoa objects so confusion for Bool! isn't an issue.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor Great point! I believe `IBOutlets` are implicitly unwrapped optionals by default, so you really don't need the `!` syntax anywhere.