# Swift: logical not operator not working

Tags: swift

this piece of code prints two times 'false':

```
println(levelController?.died)
println(!levelController?.died)
```

I don't understand why, the levelController is instantiated and the died attribute is declared in LevelController like this:

```
var died = false
```

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Swift, not Objective C.

levelController?.died is not a boolean value. It is an *optional* boolean. It can be true, false, or nil. The first println prints false. The logical not operator, applied to an optional, returns false if the optional is not nil, and true if the optional is nil. Just as it does in C when applied to a pointer.

Comment: Ok, println(levelController?.died != true) prints true, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: How to make it `true` without comparision any idea?

Comment: See answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842834/swift-good-coding-practice-if-statement-with-optional-type-bool Apple recognizes the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own not operator like this:

```
let not = (!)
```

And now we can assign a bool to test this:

```
let dead = false

if not(dead) {
print(dead)
// Code
} else {
// Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complete example, your code:

```
class Controller {
  var died: Bool = false
}

var levelController: Controller? = Controller()

println(levelController?.died)
println(!levelController?.died)
```

Outputs the following:

```
Optional(false)
false
```

The first version of your code `levelController?.died` makes use of option chaining, unwrapping the levelController and accessing the `died` property. This explains why the output is `Optional(false)`. You would typically use it as follows:

```
if let died = levelController?.died {
  if (died) {
    println("I died")
  }
}
```

The `if-let` statements unwraps this optional value.

The second version of your code `!levelController?.died` tests whether the given optional value is nil or not. You will notice that changing `died` to true of false makes no difference.

However, changing the instantiation as follows:

```
var levelController: Controller? = nil
```

Results in `!levelController?.died` becoming true. This isn't really a terribly practical piece of code!

Comment: How to make it true without comparision any idea? –  codester